# Use columns from select statement as parameter in function when joining

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

Consider the following sql query:

```
SELECT TaskId,FromItemId, IHV_FROM.NodePath as FromPath
FROM VIEW_TASKS with (nolock) 
left Join fn_ITEM_HIERARCHY(FromItemId) IHV_FROM ON FromItemId = IHV_FROM.ItemId
WHERE ...
```

fn_ITEM_HIERARCHY is a function which takes one input parameter. I would like to use FromItemId from VIEW_TASKS as input parameter to the function. 
When doing it like above, i get the error (Microsoft SQL Server 2008) "Invalid column name".

The SELECT statement returns multiple values, so it is not possible to assign the value to a variable in a separate select statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use [OUTER APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) in this case:

```
SELECT TaskId,FromItemId, IHV_FROM.NodePath as FromPath
FROM VIEW_TASKS with (nolock) 
OUTER APPLY fn_ITEM_HIERARCHY(FromItemId) IHV_FROM
WHERE ...
;
```

If the function always returns rows or if you only want results for values where the function does return rows, use CROSS APPLY instead.

Comment: Yes. I actually did. OUTER APPLY was the correct approach for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cross apply as shown here

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/03/sql-server-2005-last-ran-query-recently-ran-query/

Answer (score 0):

use alias

```
SELECT t.TaskId, t.FromItemId, IHV_FROM.NodePath as FromPath
FROM VIEW_TASKS t with (nolock) 
left Join fn_ITEM_HIERARCHY(FromItemId) IHV_FROM ON t.FromItemId = IHV_FROM.ItemId
```

Comment: Sadly this oes not work. The intellisence dots the FromItemId within the paranthesis. (and the result is still invalid column name)

Answer (score 0):

use OUTER APPLY instead of left join